“Under-determined” case of observation filter (Remote Microphone Virtual Sensing)
Introduction - Formulation
I am trying to tackle a problem of virtual sensing, where the sound field pressure is estimated at a location remote from measuring sensors. The block diagram of the system is shown in the figure below.

The form of the estimate is
$$ \hat{\mathbf{d}}_{\textrm{e}} = \mathbf{O} \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}} \tag{1} \label{1}, $$
where $\hat{\mathbf{d}}_{\textrm{e}}$ is the estimate of the sound field pressure at the remote location(s), $\mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}}$ is the sound field pressure measured at the sensors and $\mathbf{O}$ is the observation matrix that will “project” the measured data to the estimation position.
The estimation error is given by
$$ \mathbf{e} = \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}} - \hat{\mathbf{d}}_{\textrm{e}} = \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}} - \mathbf{O} \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}} \tag{2} \label{2} $$
The pressure values at the remote and measured positions are given by
$$ \begin{align}
\mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}} & = \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{e}} \mathbf{v} \tag{3.a} \label{3.a} \\
\mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}} & = \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}} \mathbf{v}, \tag{3.b} \label{3.b} \\
\end{align} $$
with $\mathbf{P}_{\textrm{e}}$ and $\mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}}$ being the transfer functions from the sources to the remote and measurement positions respectively and $\mathbf{v}$ being the source strengths.
The “conventional” formulation of the optimal observation filter is based on a least squares formulation (this ends up being a Wiener filtering approach in the frequency domain) with the cost function
$$ \begin{split}
J_{2} & = \textrm{E} \left[ \mathbf{e}^{\textrm{H}} \mathbf{e} \right] \\ 
& = \textrm{trace} \left\{ \textrm{E} \left[ \mathbf{e} \mathbf{e}^{\textrm{H}} \right] \right\} \\
& = \textrm{trace} \left\{ \textrm{E} \left[ \left( \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}} -\hat{\mathbf{d}}_{\textrm{e}}\right) \left( \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}} -\hat{\mathbf{d}}_{\textrm{e}}\right)^{\textrm{H}} \right] \right\} \\
& = \textrm{trace} \left\{ \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{ee}} - \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{me}} \mathbf{O}^{\textrm{H}} - \mathbf{O} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{me}}^{\textrm{H}} + \mathbf{O} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{mm}} \mathbf{O}^{\textrm{H}} \right\},
\end{split} \tag{4} \label{4} $$
where $\left[ \, \cdot \, \right]^{\textrm{H}}$ denotes Hermitian conjugation. The matrices $\mathbf{S}_{\textrm{ee}}$ and $\mathbf{S}_{\textrm{mm}}$ are the power spectral density matrices of the true pressure at the remote location and of the measured signals. The $\mathbf{S}_{\textrm{me}}$ matrix corresponds to the cross-spectral density between the measured and estimated quantities. The matrices are given by
$$ \begin{align}
\mathbf{S}_{\textrm{ee}} & = \textrm{E} \left[ \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}} \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}}^{\textrm{H}} \right] = \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{e}} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{vv}} \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{e}}^{\textrm{H}} \tag{5.a} \label{5.a} \\
\mathbf{S}_{\textrm{mm}} & = \textrm{E} \left[ \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}} \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}}^{\textrm{H}} \right] = \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{vv}} \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}}^{\textrm{H}} \tag{5.b} \label{5.b} \\
\mathbf{S}_{\textrm{me}} & = \textrm{E} \left[ \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}} \mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}}^{\textrm{H}} \right] = \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{e}} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{vv}} \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}}^{\textrm{H}} \tag{5.c} \label{5.c} \\
\mathbf{S}_{\textrm{vv}} & = \textrm{E} \left[ \mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^{\textrm{H}} \right] \tag{5.d} \label{5.d} \\
\end{align} $$
The solution to eq.\eqref{4} is the well-known Wiener filtering solution (without regularisation)
$$ \mathbf{O}_{\textrm{opt}} = \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{me}} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{mm}}^{-1} = \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{e}} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{vv}} \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}}^{\textrm{H}} \left( \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}} \mathbf{S}_{\textrm{vv}} \mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}}^{\textrm{H}} \right)^{-1} \tag{6} \label{6}$$
Problem statement
In the project I am working on at the moment we have been using the formula of eq.\eqref{6} to perform some investigation of the optimal filters. We have worked with both simulations and experimental data. To make sure everything is clear, the process we follow is to acquire (calculate in simulations or measure in an experiment) the transfer function matrices ($\mathbf{P}_{\textrm{e}}$ and $\mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}}$), and set $\mathbf{s}_{\textrm{vv}}$ equal to the identity matrix, to “emulate” uncorrelated sources.
The filter performs “as expected” up to the point that the number of microphones (represented as the number of rows in $\mathbf{P}_{\textrm{m}}$) becomes larger than the number of sources (size of $\mathbf{v}$ vector). When there are more microphones than sources, the estimation becomes extremely good, reaching errors of the order of $-120 \textrm{dB}$ for the simulations and $-40 \textrm{dB}$ for the measured data (perfect estimation is represented as $-\infty$) over the whole spectrum of interest (up to $4 \textrm{kHz}$, which is “outrageous” for the setups we deploy).
It has been suggested to me that this is a numerical issue and is related to the system being under-determined. Now, I am familiar with under- and over-determined systems, but what eludes me is what under- or over-determined means in this case. In the formulation and calculations, the vectors $\mathbf{d}_{\textrm{e}}$ and $\mathbf{d}_{\textrm{m}}$ are known and the unknown is the observation filter, so this is not a “generic” least-squares problem. To my understanding, the problem resembles the Blind Source Separation problem, where from measured data one can try to estimate the ”mixing matrix”, which in this case can be represented by the observation filter $\mathbf{O}$.
Any ideas on how the problem could be tackled to acquire an observation filter that does not perform to perfection (we consider this to be infeasible in practical real-life systems) would be most welcome. Comments and suggestions are also of great value as they could open paths to possible solutions.
